# Flutter: Query SQLite Database Items inside a ListView

Tags: sqlite, listview, flutter

I have created a class for write, stroe and fetch data from the database.
This is my code for the Database-Helper:
**DatenbankClient.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_app/datenbank/Besitzen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/datenbank/Kategorie.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/datenbank/Rezepte.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/datenbank/Zutat.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DatenbankClient{
  Database _db;

  Future create() async{
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "datenbank.db");

    _db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1,
      onCreate: this._create);
  }


  //Erstellt die Tabellen
  Future _create(Database db, int version) async{

    await db.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE kategorie (
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
           titel TEXT NOT NULL)                    
    """);

    await db.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE rezepte (
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
           kategorie_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
           name TEXT NOT NULL,
           beschreibung TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
           favorit INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
           anzahl_pers INTEGER NOT NULL,
           termin TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
           FOREIGN KEY(kategorie_ID) REFERENCES kategorie(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE
    """);


    await db.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE zutaten (
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
           anzahl INTEGER NOT NULL,
           name TEXT NOT NULL,
           einheit TEXT NOT NULL,
           rezept_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE)          
    """);


    await db.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE besitzen (
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
           rezept_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
           zutat_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
           FOREIGN KEY(rezept_ID) REFERENCES rezepte(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
           FOREIGN KEY(zutat_ID) REFERENCES zutaten(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE)
    """);
  }


  //Neue Einträge hinzufügen
  Future upsertKategorie(Kategorie kategorie) async{
    var count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await _db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM kategorie WHERE titel = ?", [kategorie.titel]));
    if(count == 0){
      kategorie.id = await _db.insert("kategorie", kategorie.toMap());
    } else{
      await _db.update("kategorie", kategorie.toMap(), where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [kategorie.id]);
    }

    return kategorie;
  }

  Future upsertRezept(Rezepte rezept) async{
    var count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await _db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM rezepte WHERE name = ?", [rezept.name]));
    if(count == 0){
      rezept.id = await _db.insert("rezept", rezept.toMap());
    } else{
      await _db.update("rezept", rezept.toMap(), where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [rezept.id]);
    }

    return rezept;
  }

  Future upsertZutat(Zutat zutat) async{
    var count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await _db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM zutaten WHERE rezept_ID = ?", [zutat.rezept_ID]));
    if(count == 0){
      zutat.id = await _db.insert("rezept", zutat.toMap());
    } else{
      await _db.update("zutat", zutat.toMap(), where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [zutat.id]);
    }

    return zutat;
  }

  Future upsertBesitzt(Besitzen besitzt) async{
    var count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await _db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM besitzen WHERE id = ?", [besitzt.id]));
    if(count == 0){
      besitzt.id = await _db.insert("rezept", besitzt.toMap());
    } else{
      await _db.update("zutat", besitzt.toMap(), where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [besitzt.id]);
    }

    return besitzt;
  }


  //Einträge herausholen
  Future fetchKategorie(int id) async{
    List ergebnis = await _db.query("Kategorie", columns: Kategorie.columns, where: "id=?", whereArgs: [id]);
    Kategorie kategorie = Kategorie.fromMap(ergebnis[0]);

    return kategorie;
  }

  Future fetchRezepte(int id) async{
    List ergebnis = await _db.query("Rezept", columns: Rezepte.columns, where: "id=?", whereArgs: [id]);
    Rezepte rezept = Rezepte.fromMap(ergebnis[0]);

    return rezept;
  }

  Future fetchZutaten(int id) async{
    List ergebnis = await _db.query("Zutat", columns: Zutat.columns, where: "id=?", whereArgs: [id]);
    Zutat zutat = Zutat.fromMap(ergebnis[0]);

    return zutat;
  }

  Future fetchBesitzen(int id) async{
    List ergebnis = await _db.query("Besitzt", columns: Besitzen.columns, where: "id=?", whereArgs: [id]);
    Besitzen besitzen = Besitzen.fromMap(ergebnis[0]);

    return besitzen;
  }

  Future fetchRezeptZutat(int zutatID) async{
    List ergebnis = await _db.query("zutat", columns: Zutat.columns, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [zutatID]);
    Zutat zutat = Zutat.fromMap(ergebnis[0]);
    zutat.rezept_ID = await fetchRezepte(zutat.rezept_ID);

    return zutat;
  }
}
```

Through this dart-Class I'm saving the recipes that the user is inserting, then to fetch the name of the recipe is:

```
rezepte = await datenbankClient.fetchRezepte(rezepte.id);
```

But I do not know how to display them in a ListView. Does anybody have an idea how i could be able to that in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you have several elements I'd say that a `ListBuilder`
is your best option.

```
new ListView.builder(
  itemCount: rezepte.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final String item = _rezepte[index];
    return new ListTile(
      title: new Text(item["title"])
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it is throwing me an error at itemCount: "The getter 'length' is not defined for the class Rezepte". And I do not know where I should get the varialbe "_rezepte". Sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: That sounds like the data has not yet been fetched to the rezepte object. You need to implement some way of checking if the object contains data before building your list.

Comment: If you're looking for a good async plugin that helps you with handling this, then I recommend [async loader](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async_loader).